# How i edit image with data in image model using img_id send in post method

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views

1. How to edit image using post method
2. post method instead of put method
3. send pk in form data instead of url
4. over all look more sophisticated method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Complete Guide of the question**

`models.py`

```
class UploadImage(models.Model):

img_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='img', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
like_choice =[
    ('0','0'),
    ('1','1')
]
is_liked = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices = like_choice, default='0')
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.image)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class EditImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UploadImage
        fields = ['img_id','user_id','image','is_liked']
```

`views.py`

```
class EditImageAPIView(APIView):

    serializer_class = EditImageSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        img_id = request.data.get('img_id')

        editobj = UploadImage.objects.get(img_id=img_id)
        serializer = EditImageSerializer(editobj, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({
                'status' : True,
                'message' : 'Image Edited Successfully',
                'data' : serializer.data
            },status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            
        return Response({
            'status' : 'False',
            'message' : 'Error! Image with this id does not exist!'
        }, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`urls.py`

```
    url(r'^edit_image', EditImageAPIView.as_view(), name='edit image without pk'),
```